# Choosing a type of array antenna

Tags: antenna-construction, phased-array

I want to design a steerable beam array antenna which has 15 dBi directivity using uniform fed infinitesimal dipole elements at 1GHz frequency occupying physical aperture.

Considering that phases of elements have beam shift of 20 degrees, which type of array antenna I should chose? End fire or broad side? Any other type?

Comment: For a steerable beam it probably needs to be broadside not endfire, eh?

Comment: Please don't dump your homework questions on us without investing some effort of your own first.

Comment: the problem of Stack Exchange is that, here, there are a bunch of professionals who want to be challenged by others' questions and they don't care about beginners whom their (maybe) simple questions might sound tough to them! Also, everyone answers so late that the answer doesn't help anymore!!!

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Please excuse me for joking, but it sounds like you want to use the elusive isotropic antennas to build this thing.   As far as I know, those only exist in FCC tests.  But seriously, sterability requires utilizing  different phases for each element.  Companies like Raytheon charge millions and millions of dollars for systems to do that.  This might be a bit ambitious.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to design a steerable beam array antenna which has 15 dBi directivity using uniform fed infinitesimal dipole elements at 1GHz frequency occupying physical aperture.

Array elements cannot be uniformly fed and steerable. Steering is most simply provided by applying a linear phase distribution across elements. Kieth is correct that gain/directivity will be a function of the antenna used as elements of the array, as well as spacing, phasing, and number of elements.

I provided a basic explanation of beam steering [over here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/how-to-feed-an-array-of-dipoles-for-an-end-fire-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

The type of array you use will affect mostly the GAIN and DIRECTIVITY. ANY antenna can be used in an array. It just depends on your goals and what is best for the situation. Broadside or endfire? It depends if you want vertically/horizontally wide or narrow patterns and how broad of a main lobe. Spacing and phasing will also affect the pattern.